# MDX filtering results by date

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap

I want to filter results of my query, so it returns values only if date is greater than specified.

I wrote something like that:

```
SELECT { [Measures].[Net sales] } ON COLUMNS
    FROM [Sales]
    WHERE ( { [Department].[Department name].&[WRO], [Department].[Department name].&[KAT]},
            {( FILTER([Time].[Date], [Date].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_KEY >= '2015-10-10'))} );
```

but it does return null. Without this part with `filter()` it returns whole `[Net sales]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Net sales NEW] AS 
   SUM(
     FILTER(
      [Time].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS, 
      [Time].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_KEY 
          >= 20151010
     )
     , [Measures].[Net sales]
   )
SELECT 
      {
       [Measures].[Net sales]
      ,[Measures].[Net sales NEW] 
      } ON 0
FROM  [Sales]
WHERE {
       [Department].[Department name].&[WRO]
     , [Department].[Department name].&[KAT]
       };
```

Another approach:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Date_key] AS 
      [Time].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_KEY 
MEMBER [Measures].[Net sales NEW] AS 
   SUM(
      [Time].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS, 
      IIF(
         [Measures].[Date_key] >= 20151010
       , [Measures].[Net sales]
       , NULL
      )
   )
SELECT 
      {
       [Measures].[Net sales]
      ,[Measures].[Net sales NEW] 
      } ON 0
FROM  [Sales]
WHERE {
       [Department].[Department name].&[WRO]
     , [Department].[Department name].&[KAT]
       };
```

One question: is this definitely the format of your date keys? '2015-10-10'

A possible visual way to check your keys, against your WHERE slicer, is to have a simpler script something like this:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Date_key] AS 
      [Time].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_KEY 
SELECT 
      [Measures].[Date_key] ON 0
      [Time].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM  [Sales]
WHERE {
       [Department].[Department name].&[WRO]
     , [Department].[Department name].&[KAT]
      };
```

Unsure what is wrong with the above - I willneed to test tomorrow against the AdvWrks cube.

Again another approach might be:

```
SELECT 
      [Measures].[Net sales] } ON 0
FROM  [Sales]
WHERE ( 
         { [Department].[Department name].&[WRO]
         , [Department].[Department name].&[KAT] }
         , {[Time].[Date].[Date].&[10 Oct 2015]:null} 
      );
```

note: you need to change `10 Oct 2015` to the formatting in your cube & `10 Oct 2015` must be a date that exists in the cube.

Comment: In your first example i'm getting #Error as value for column Net Sales NEW.
And yes, date key is in format of 20130103, not 2013-01-03. But my query still doesn't work.

Comment: I changed the filter condition to a number. Does it still error? If it does then if you double click on #error, in ssms, what does it say? (you should get a description of the error). Whoops I can see an error in the WHERE clause - let me amend.

Comment: sorry, this #error was caused by mine mistake, but now it returns same values for both Net Sales and Net Sales NEW

Comment: @Dodzik OK - this is more positive. If you amend 20151010 to say 20160301 what happens? Also if you run the second script what is the minimum and maximum values given for Date_key?

Comment: If I change date, value for Net sales NEW is still the same, it doesn't change. 
20130101 to 20161231

Comment: @Dodzik I added another approach - although, currently, I do not have AdvWrks to prototype any of these ideas against, so not too hopeful!

Comment: Unfortunately still nothing, it just changed formatting from 111,111,111.1 to 111111111.1

Comment: am I assuming wrongly about the structure of your cube with the following? `[Time].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS`  .... does the Time dim have a Date hierarchy which has a Date level?

Comment: Your last approach is working! Many thanks to you for help! Have a nice day :)

Comment: @Dodzik cool. I will correct the other approaches tomorrow once I have AdvWrks cube to play with

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT { [Measures].[Net sales] } ON COLUMNS
FROM [Sales]
WHERE ( { [Department].[Department name].&[WRO], [Department].[Department name].&[KAT]},
       {( FILTER([Time].[Date], [Date].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_KEY > '2015-10-10'))} );
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if changing this `>=` to this `>` is the answer.